# Adding Jquery to ASP.Net created Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I have a gridview that puts a drop down list in every cell of a certain column.

I want all the dropdownlists to implement a Jquery select class. The normal way to do this is as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#language").selectbox();
});
</script>
```

Now the problem is there will be multiple with different ID's so I cant set it this way.. Is there any way to set all drop down lists as per their cssclass or a way to do it inline? (ie i can add attributes to the dropdownlist through C#)

Comment: Why not using the class selector? `$(".language").selectbox();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select multiple elements by their ids just specify them as a comma separated list as a selector

```
$("#id1,#id2,#id3")
```

If all the elements you want to select has a class use a dot `.` before the class in the selector

```
$(".yourclass")
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/